# Get values from an object array, inside another array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the following content in an PHP array.

Array content with ***print_r***:

```
Array ( [0] => Networks Object (
    [_data:Networks:private] => Array (
        [id] => 213
        [name] => Netflix
        [logo_path] => /wwemzKWzjKYJFfCeiB57q3r4Bcm.png
        [origin_country] =>
        )
    )
)
```

Array content with ***var_dump***

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> object(Networks)#10 (1) {
        ["_data":"Networks":private]=> array(4) {
            ["id"]=> int(213)
            ["name"]=> string(7) "Netflix"
            ["logo_path"]=> string(32) "/wwemzKWzjKYJFfCeiB57q3r4Bcm.png"
            ["origin_country"]=> string(0) ""
        }
    }
}
```

**---update---**

The class

```
<?php
class Networks {
    private $_data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->_data = $data;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->_data['name'];
    }
}
?>
```

How can I get the ["name"] value Netflix?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have the code that defines the `Networks` class?

Comment: I have updated the question with the class.

Comment: `$array[0]->getName()` should do it ;)

Comment: OK, that's helpful. If your array is stored in the variable `$myArray`, then you can access the network name like this: `echo $myArray[0]->getName();`.

Comment: Tanks both of you! :-D